# C# Invoking a method using reflection in a generic manner

Tags: c#, reflection, named-pipes

I have two processes (A and B), both have a method Foo(SomeClass paramA, SomeOtherClass paramB).
The processes communicate using Windows Pipes (not WCF) and can send and receive messages of type:

```
public class PipeMessageArgs
{
     public PipeMessageArgs(string i_MethodName, List<object> i_Args)
      {
          MethodName = i_MethodName;
          Args = i_Args;
      }

      public string MethodName { get; private set; }
      public List<object> Args { get; private set; }
}
```

When calling Foo on A, I want to invoke Foo on B, with the same values.

This is the calling code in A:

```
public void Foo(SomeClass paramA, SomeOtherClass paramB)
{
    var args = new List<object> { paramA, paramB };
    m_Server.PushMessage(new PipeMessageArgs(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, args));
}
```

This is the invoking code in B:

```
void ClientOnReceiveMessage(NamedPipeConnection i_Connection, object i_Message)
{
    var pipeMessageArgs = i_Message as PipeMessageArgs;
    GetType().GetMethod(pipeMessageArgs.MethodName).Invoke(this, pipeMessageArgs.Args.ToArray());
}
```

But as you can see, I have to manually create a list of parameters for each call so if I forget a parameter or get the order wrong, things will not work. Given that I cannot use reflection to get the values, and I do not want to use the profiler (performance is an issue), what is the best way to make it more generic?

Edit: I cannot use WCF for too many reasons (actually, I am moving away from WCF). I am using pipes, namely PipeStream.

Edit2: What I want is a solution that does not rely on manually creating arrays of parameters; something that can create this array automatically for me.

Comment: hmm. instead of a list you could use a Dictionary<string,object> and put the parameter name in the key?

Comment: But really I would look to make it _less_ generic and create some strongly typed communication method. not sure how much you can change?

Comment: Yeah I know I can overcome the ordering issue, what I really want is something more generic - something that will save me manually declaring a collection of values.

Comment: you could use a post compiler like postsharp to autogenerate the list methods for you. but you're just saving typing

Comment: or change all your methods to accept a single parameter list as the parameter. then you can just send this on unchanged

Comment: Are you saying that the code "I do it like this" is actually part of your `A.Foo()` method? Or are you invoking the method via some other mechanism. Personally, the vague description seems like you ought to be using some remoting API, e.g. WCF or similar, instead of reinventing yourself. In any case, without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows the details of your scenario, it's not really possible to fully understand your question, never mind offer a good answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I added some more minimal and somewhat complete code. I cannot use WCF for too many reasons (actually, I am moving away from WCF). I am using pipes, namely PipeStream..

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you are trying to accomplish when you say you want it "more generic".  I understand your comment that you are looking for something that will save you manually declaring a collection of values.  For that, would the params keyword suffice on the constructor?  Something like public PipeMessageArgs(string i_MethodName, params object[] i_Args)?

Comment: I meant something that will completely spare me even the declaration of such array, Something that will automatically create it for me, preventing me from creating it wrong. I ended up solving it by using RealProxy, I'm just about to write my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [RealProxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). RealProxy is mainly used for remoting but can allow you to create proxy for classes. You can then add functionality before each method call (also properties calls). I used this very nice [blog post](http://blog.benoitblanchon.fr/realproxy/) to implement it.

This is my proxy:

```
public class InvokingProxy : RealProxy
    {
        private readonly INamedPipe _namedPipe;

        InvokingProxy(object i_Target, INamedPipe i_NamedPipe) : base(i_Target.GetType())
        {
            _namedPipe = i_NamedPipe;
        }

        public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage i_Msg)
        {
            var methodCall = i_Msg as IMethodCallMessage;

            if (methodCall != null)
            {
                return HandleMethodCall(methodCall);
            }

            return null;
        }

        IMessage HandleMethodCall(IMethodCallMessage i_MethodCall)
        {
            _namedPipe.PushMessage(new PipeMessageArgs(i_MethodCall.MethodName, i_MethodCall.InArgs));
            return new ReturnMessage(null, null, 0, i_MethodCall.LogicalCallContext, i_MethodCall);
        }

        public static T Wrap<T>(T i_Target, INamedPipe i_NamedPipe) where T : MarshalByRefObject
        {
            return (T)new InvokingProxy(i_Target, i_NamedPipe).GetTransparentProxy();
        }
    }
```

I use i_MethodCall.InArgs to get the in-arguments, that's the hear of the issue. Also notice how HandleMethodCall uses the pipe to push a message instead of actually calling the requested method. This means that my 'API' class is actually just empty methods with no implementation (I can always add more implementation there and invoke the method before/after the pipe action):

```
class Api : MarshalByRefObject, IApi
    {
        public void Foo(SomeClass paramA, SomeOtherClass paramB)
        {
        }

        public void Bar(SomeClassX paramA, SomeOtherClassY paramB)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Also, as a requirement of RealProxy. the class has to inherit from MarshalByRefObject which was fine by me as it has no other functionality. Read more about it in the blog post I linked.